# Decode Unicode (Korean) characters in C

Tags: c, string, unicode, webserver, decode

I am making a web server in C language. I need to get parameter from the url for my calculation. The problem is there is one field (name) that people can type unicode characters. However, when my server receive that request, these unicode characters become something I don't understand. Ex:

```
http://192.168.1.1:10001/reg_me?name=박우중&studentid=2012003427
```

turn to be

```
http://192.168.1.1:10001/reg_me?name=%EB%B0%95%EC%9A%B0%EC%A4%91&studentid=2012003427
```

So I cannot get that field. Is there any way I can decode these strange characters to get the original ones?

Comment: those  strange characters are the hex utf-8. just parse it as hex, "character by character" and you'll have the utf-8 encoded korean

Comment: Can you tell me in more detail or give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have saved your three Korean signs into a file called *korean*, placed it right next to the executable I have generated from the C source code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {

    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen( "korean", "r" );

    if ( fp == NULL ) {
        printf( "Failure at line %d\n", __LINE__ );
        return -1;
    }

    int currentchar;
    while ( ( currentchar = fgetc( fp ) ) != EOF ) {
        printf( "%%%X ", currentchar );
    }

    putchar( 10 );
    return 0;
}
```

The first two percent signs `%%` are just to have a single percent sign right before my `%X`, which will print the `currentchar` in base 16, hexadecimal, capitalized. You can think of it as an escape sequence specific for the `%`. The output has been:

```
%EB %B0 %95 %EC %9A %B0 %EC %A4 %91
```

As you may realize, this is exactly the sequence you've reported. You can use this fact to decode these values back to your Korean characters. Let's revert the process; save the percent-encoded sequence with percent signs and without spaces into a file, name the file *percentencoded*, and use the following C source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {

    FILE * decodee;
    FILE * percentencoded;

    decodee = fopen( "decodee", "w" );
    percentencoded = fopen( "percentencoded", "r" );

    if ( decodee == NULL || percentencoded == NULL ) {
        printf( "Failure at line %d\n", __LINE__ );
        return -1;
    }

    int currentchar;
    while ( fscanf( percentencoded, "%%%X", &currentchar ) == 1 ) {
        fputc( currentchar, decodee );
    }

    putchar( 10 );
    return 0;
}
```

The file *percentencoded* had the following inside it:

```
%EB%B0%95%EC%9A%B0%EC%A4%91
```

And the generated file *decodee* now has the following inside it:

```
박우중
```

I hope this helps you, somehow...

Answer (score 1):

So here's some C code to do what i mentioned in the comment.
assuming you're just getting a string in the above like `"%EB%B0%95%EC%9A%B0%EC%A4%91"`

```
parse(char * in, char * out){
  strtok(in, "%"); // Note, the first token is empty, because the first character is a delimiter
  char *token;
  while(token = strtok(NULL,"%)){
    unsigned c;
    sscanf(token, "%x", c);
    if(c > 0xFF) return -1;
    *out++=c;
  }
  *out++ = '\0';
  return 0;
}
```

its a primitive parser, but it should do nicely for this simple problem. im sure this exists somewhere already though